# Is there any difference between "value" attribute to be empty and no value attribute at all in html?

Tags: html

Is there any difference between the following?

```
<input value/>
<input value=""/>
<input />
```

Comment: <input value=""/> specifies a value, however the others doesn't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are differences, but only between two firsts and last one : [from specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty)

> Note that empty attribute syntax is exactly equivalent to specifying the empty string as the value for the attribute.

JS wise: two first will make `getAttribute` return an empty string, while last one will return `null`.
For all 3, `value` property will be an empty string.

CSS wise, `input[value]` will match only the 2 firsts.

```js
var inp = document.querySelectorAll('input'),
  attr;
for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
  attr = inp[i].getAttribute('value')
  console.log(i, 'attr:', '[' + typeof attr + '] ' + attr, 'val:', '[' + typeof inp[i].value + '] ', inp[i].value);
}
```

```css
input[value] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input value/>
<input value="" />
<input>
```

But note that this is only for `<input>` tag.
Other elements have other behaviours (e.g MediaElement and the `controls` attribute)

```js
var vid = document.querySelectorAll('video'),
  attr;
for (var i = 0; i < vid.length; i++) {
  attr = vid[i].getAttribute('controls')
  console.log(i, 'attr:', '[' + typeof attr + '] ' + attr,  'val:', '[' + typeof vid[i].controls + '] ', vid[i].controls);
}
```

```html
<video controls></video>
<video controls=""></video>
<video controls="true"></video>
<video controls="false"></video>
```